# Installing packages using requirements.txt for Azure function fails without info

Tags: python, azure-functions

I need to deploy some dependencies for an Azure function. I used the requirements.txt file which I used during development.

```
albumentations==1.2.0
certifi==2022.6.15
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
cycler==0.11.0
Cython==0.29.30
fonttools==4.33.3
idna==3.3
imageio==2.19.3
joblib==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.4.3
matplotlib==3.5.2
networkx==2.8.4
numpy==1.22.4
opencv-contrib-python==4.6.0.66
opencv-python==4.6.0.66
packaging==21.3
Pillow==9.1.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
PyWavelets==1.3.0
PyYAML==6.0
qudida==0.0.4
requests==2.28.0
scikit-image==0.18.3
scikit-learn==1.1.1
scipy==1.8.1
six==1.16.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
tifffile==2022.5.4
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
torch
torchaudio
torchvision
typing-extensions==4.2.0
urllib3==1.26.9
setuptools
pycocotools@git+https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git@cocodataset-master#subdirectory=PythonAPI
```

This is the output of the installation, but I can not see what went wrong. As the log says the log file is empty, is there another way to get the output of the pip command?

```
17:44:14 HttpExampleTest: Starting deployment...
17:44:18 HttpExampleTest: Creating zip package...
17:44:18 HttpExampleTest: Zip package size: 5.04 kB
17:44:19 HttpExampleTest: Fetching changes.
17:44:20 HttpExampleTest: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/00a1594a-2f9c-48cc-9699-355ee2ebb600.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
17:44:24 HttpExampleTest: Updating submodules.
17:44:26 HttpExampleTest: Preparing deployment for commit id 'c5f1676a-e'.
17:44:26 HttpExampleTest: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
17:44:26 HttpExampleTest: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
17:44:26 HttpExampleTest: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
17:44:30 HttpExampleTest: Running oryx build...
17:44:30 HttpExampleTest: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /tmp/build/expressbuild --platform python --platform-version 3.9 -i /tmp/8da7bb05ee9726c -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
17:44:32 HttpExampleTest: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
17:44:32 HttpExampleTest: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
17:44:32 HttpExampleTest: Oryx Version: 0.2.20220308.4, Commit: c92fa6a2d6fc14dc9646f80e2bb2e393a5cdc258, ReleaseTagName: 20220308.4
17:44:32 HttpExampleTest: Build Operation ID: |U4gOM1NlBik=.4334ee06_
17:44:32 HttpExampleTest: Repository Commit : c5f1676a-e09a-4550-b757-823b430f291e
17:44:32 HttpExampleTest: Detecting platforms...
17:44:37 HttpExampleTest: Detected following platforms:
17:44:37 HttpExampleTest:   python: 3.9.7
17:44:37 HttpExampleTest: Using intermediate directory '/tmp/8da7bb05ee9726c'.
17:44:38 HttpExampleTest: Copying files to the intermediate directory...
17:44:38 HttpExampleTest: Done in 0 sec(s).
17:44:38 HttpExampleTest: Source directory     : /tmp/8da7bb05ee9726c
17:44:38 HttpExampleTest: Destination directory: /tmp/build/expressbuild
17:44:38 HttpExampleTest: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9
17:44:38 HttpExampleTest: Creating directory for command manifest file if it doesnot exist
17:44:38 HttpExampleTest: Removing existing manifest file
17:44:38 HttpExampleTest: Running pip install...
17:44:44 HttpExampleTest: Done in 6 sec(s).
17:44:44 HttpExampleTest: "2022-08-11 15:44:44"|ERROR|ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. | Exit code: 1 | Please review your requirements.txt | More information: https://aka.ms/troubleshoot-python
17:44:46 HttpExampleTest: /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /tmp/build/expressbuild --platform python --platform-version 3.9 -i /tmp/8da7bb05ee9726c -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
17:44:46 HttpExampleTest: Generating summary of Oryx build
17:44:46 HttpExampleTest: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
17:44:47 HttpExampleTest: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
17:44:50 HttpExampleTest: Deployment Failed.
```

Any help is very appreciate.

Comment: Sometimes this occurs because of the Storage Account was not accessible to the Function App because when you create a function manually, it will spin it's own storage, you have to do some changes inside local settings.json file.

Check and try to change the connection strings stored in the AzureWebJobsStorage & AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING in App Settings.

And also check requirements.txt file must be in the project root for dependencies to be installed.